# Java: wait() and notify() confusion

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I'm trying to implement a condition that only one thread to access: Let's say it's a bottle of water - I want only 1 person (thread) to be able to have it a time. Everything seems to work smoothly but I can't get the printing to be shown - the one before the call to `wait()`; .

```
public synchronized void getBotttle  {
    while(myCondition) {
      try {
        System.out.println("Printing that is never done?!");
        wait();
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    System.out.println("Printing that works");
    myCondition = true;
    notifyAll(); //or notify(), tried both

    try {
      Thread.sleep(time); // 
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    System.out.println("Printing again");
    methodToMakeConditionFalse();
   // notifyAll(); even if I put it here its still the same
}
```

This method is called by the threads and it works as intended - only 1 thread has the "bottle" but the printing isn't there.
Any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to tell, without being able to see the surrounding code, but it looks like the value of `myCondition` must be `false`, which is preventing entry into your `while` loop; otherwise, the `System.out.println` statement should be executed. One other thing that I see: your code is formatted as if you are including a complete `while` structure; however, the parenthesis don't match throughout the entire code sample, so the closing brace (`}`) that follows your first `try`-`catch` is actually closing the `while` loop. Is your code structure correct?

Comment: Just to be clear, is this all really just one block of code? Or is it two blocks of code, each running on the same thread? As it stands now, assuming this is all surrounded by a `synchronized` block (which you didn't include in the question), the `wait()` method would wait indefinitely for a `notify()` _from another thread_ that will never come. The notify can't come from this thread, because the thread will never even get to it, because it's still waiting for notification. You've essentially deadlocked on yourself, so to speak.

Comment: Edited my post to be easier to read and understand. This is 1 block of code - a synchronized method that Threads call when they have to use a "shared" object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a complete example, which makes it hard to tell what you're doing wrong; my guess is that your condition flag isn't set appropriately. Here is a complete example which works, it makes sure that only one thread has access to a resource at a time.

```
public class StuffExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
        Worker worker = new Worker(new StuffHolder());
        Thread t1 = new Thread(worker); 
        Thread t2 = new Thread(worker); 

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        Thread.sleep(10000L);
        t1.interrupt();
        t2.interrupt();
    }
}

class Worker implements Runnable {
    private StuffHolder holder;

    public Worker(StuffHolder holder) {
        this.holder = holder;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                holder.useStuff();
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}

class StuffHolder {

    private boolean inUse = false;
    private int count = 0;
    public synchronized void useStuff() throws InterruptedException {
        while (inUse) {
            wait();
        }
        inUse = true;
        System.out.println("doing whatever with stuff now, count=" 
            + count + ", thread=" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        count += 1;
        inUse = false;
        notifyAll();
    }   
}
```

Output is:

```
doing whatever with stuff now, count=0, threadid=Thread-0
doing whatever with stuff now, count=1, threadid=Thread-1
doing whatever with stuff now, count=2, threadid=Thread-0
doing whatever with stuff now, count=3, threadid=Thread-1
doing whatever with stuff now, count=4, threadid=Thread-0
doing whatever with stuff now, count=5, threadid=Thread-1
doing whatever with stuff now, count=6, threadid=Thread-0
doing whatever with stuff now, count=7, threadid=Thread-1
doing whatever with stuff now, count=8, threadid=Thread-0
doing whatever with stuff now, count=9, threadid=Thread-1
doing whatever with stuff now, count=10, threadid=Thread-0
doing whatever with stuff now, count=11, threadid=Thread-1
doing whatever with stuff now, count=12, threadid=Thread-0
doing whatever with stuff now, count=13, threadid=Thread-1
doing whatever with stuff now, count=14, threadid=Thread-0
doing whatever with stuff now, count=15, threadid=Thread-1
doing whatever with stuff now, count=16, threadid=Thread-1
doing whatever with stuff now, count=17, threadid=Thread-0
doing whatever with stuff now, count=18, threadid=Thread-1
doing whatever with stuff now, count=19, threadid=Thread-0
```

See [Oracle's tutorial on guarded blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).

Comment: Which Thread will be able get to while(inUse) condition? Suspect no one, apart of the very first one. So it's just approach to reinvent mutex which already implemented in Java and called monitor.

Comment: @Ivan: added thread name to example to show that both threads access this

Comment: I can only mark one reply as the best answer and I'll mark this but both you and Ivan helped much, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively answer is very simple, signature of your `getBotttle()` method has keyword `synchronized` which means never and ever two different threads will access this code simultaneously. So, whole block with `while(myCondition) { ... }` is fruitless.

Secondly, I recommend you to look into `java.util.concurrent.*` package.

UPD. Seems worth to clarify what's usual usecase for wait/notifyAll is:

```
public class WaitNotify {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new WaitNotify().go();
    }

    private void go() throws InterruptedException {
        ResourceProvider provider = new ResourceProvider();
        Consumer c1 = new Consumer("consumer1", provider);
        Consumer c2 = new Consumer("consumer2", provider);
        Consumer c3 = new Consumer("consumer3", provider);
        Consumer[] consumers = new Consumer[] { c1, c2, c3 };

        for (int i = 0; i < consumers.length; i++) {
            provider.grant(consumers[i]);
        }
    }

    public static class ResourceProvider {
        private Resource resource = new Resource();

        public synchronized void grant(Consumer consumer) throws InterruptedException {
            while (resource == null) {
                wait();
            }
            consumer.useResource(resource);
            resource = null;
        }

        public synchronized void putBack(Resource resource) {
            this.resource = resource;
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public static class Resource {
        public void doSomething(String consumer) {
            System.out.println("I'm working! " + consumer);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3L * 1000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
    }

    public static class Consumer implements Runnable {
        private String consumer;
        private Resource resource;
        private ResourceProvider provider;

        public Consumer(String consumer, ResourceProvider provider) {
            this.consumer = consumer;
            this.provider = provider;
        }

        public void useResource(Resource r) {
            this.resource = r;
            new Thread(this).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            resource.doSomething(consumer);
            provider.putBack(resource);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A big thanks to both of you. I will try write everything clear so other people stuck at something similar can work it out.

What I had is 2 Threads (lets say 2 people). They both have to drink water from 1 bottle, so when the bottle is in use the 2nd person has to wait. My code looked roughly like this:

```
class Bottle{
 private boolean inUse=false;

 public synchronized void getBotttle(String name, int time)  {
    while(inUse) {
      try {
        System.out.println("The bottle is in use. You have to wait");
        wait();
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    System.out.println("Person "+name+" is using the bottle");
    inUse = true;
    notify(); //or notifyAll(), tried both

    try {
      Thread.sleep(time); // sleep the Thread with the person that is drinking at the moment for some time in order for him to finish
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    System.out.println("The bottle is now free");
    inUse=false;
   // notify(); even if I put it here its still the same
 }
}
```

I just started using Threads in java so I wasn't sure where the notify() should really go. What is more I didn't understand that notify() releases the lock only after all the block that has the keyword synchronized is executed. In my case that was not what I wanted and as happens when the lock is released the condition for the while method will be false and the printing will not be executed. The fact that the program was waiting properly and as intended made it hard for me to spot this.

And this is what I wanted and what I got working:

```
class Bottle{
 private boolean inUse=false;

 public void getBotttle(String name, int time)  {
    while(inUse) {
      try {
        System.out.println("The bottle is in use. You have to wait.");
        synchronized(this){
         wait();
        }
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    System.out.println("Person "+name+" is using the bottle");
    inUse = true;

    try {
      Thread.sleep(time); // sleep the Thread with the person that is drinking at the moment for some time in order for him to finish
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    System.out.println("The bottle is free now.");
    inUse=false;
    synchronized(this){
     notifyAll();
    }
 }
}
```

Hopefully last edit:
This should prevent 2 threads from skipping the while loop and should be the solution I was looking for

```
class Bottle{
 private boolean inUse=false;

 public synchronized void getBotttle(String name, int time)  {
    while(inUse) {
      try {
        System.out.println("The bottle is in use. You have to wait.");
        wait();
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    System.out.println("Person "+name+" is using the bottle");
    inUse = true;
 }

 public synchronized void sleeping(String name, int time)
    try {
      Thread.sleep(time); // sleep the Thread with the person that is drinking at the moment for some time in order for him to finish
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    notifyAll();
    System.out.println("The bottle is free now.");
    inUse=false;
 }
}
```

Edit:
Guess not, printing that bottle is in use is not executed agian...

Comment: from the last piece of code it appears you've missed the point. if you release the lock and then set the flag you allow another thread to jump in and modify the flag and even get access to the shared resource, so this isn't threadsafe at all. take a look at the Oracle tutorials I linked to.

Comment: Isn't whats in the tutorial similar to what I'm doing, just my actual threads that use the object are in different class, and at some point they call Bottle.getBottle(); the first one to call it, will skip the while because the condition is false initially, will print that it has the bottle, sets the flag to true and sleeps for some time. By the time it is sleeping, thread 2 tries to call Bottle.getBottle(); and gets in the while loop and waits there untill Thread 1 wakes up and changes the flag to false and notifies the other thread that the flag has been changed?

Comment: After a thread stops waiting and give up the lock and *before* that thread can set isUsed to true, another thread can enter the same method, blow past the loop and set isUsed to true. once you release a lock you can't know what the system state is.

Comment: The initial state of the inUse is false, so you are saying there could be a chance where 2 threads enter the method at the same time and both skip the while loop? I would need to synchronize bigger part of the method if I get it right, but synchronizing the method itself will result to the printing being not executed again. Will separating the method into 2, just after inUse = true; , and making both methods synchronized be a better solution ?

Comment: Did it in 2 methods, both synchronized, one has the while condition with wait and ends up with the flag=true; , other method has the sleep, notify and then changes the flag. 1st Method is always called before 2nd. In this case I am sure that only 1 thread will be executing each method. Thread 1 will skip the while loop, change the flag and go to sleep method. Thread 2 will enter the while then and stay there until Thread 1 wakes up, notifies and changes the flag.